# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'demo'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am trying to connect to database with my hibernate application.
But I am not able to connect with other databases except **Test**.

It is strange because if I would create any database it will not allow me to access it through hibernate except test DB which is predefined in phpMyAdmin.

I tried these many things but it did not work.

1.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH     GRANT OPTION;
```

2.

```
    mysql -u root -p
```

3.

```
     mysqladmin -u root password 'root password goes here'
```

4. I have reinstalled my wamp server.

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
   <hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property  name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> 
   <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo</property> 
   <property name="username">root</property> 
   <property name="password" /> 
   <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>  
   <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
   <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <!-- disabled 2nd level catche
   <property   name="catche.provider_class">org.hibernate.catche.NoCatcheProvider</property>-->
    <!-- enabled 2nd level catche -->
  <property name="catche.use_second_level_catche">true</property>
  <property name="catche.use_query_catche">true</property>

  <property name="catche.provider_class">org.hibernate.catche.EhCatcheProvider</property>   
   <mapping class="org.hibernet.src.userDetails" ></mapping>
   <mapping class="org.hibernet.src.Address" ></mapping>
   <mapping class="org.hibernet.src.Vehicle" ></mapping>    
 </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

If it would be a syntax problem it should not work with test database but its working with it.
What should I do?

Comment: first off you should probably not be using root, rather create another user..have you tried to `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH  GRANT OPTION;`  So that you can use the root user to connect from anywhere?

Comment: `IDENTIFIED BY 'root'` . So password is also root, Then use it in the xml configuration file  `<property name="username">root</property> 
   <property name="password" >root</property> `

Comment: Yes its allow me to create a connection because I can access test database
So I dont think password is necessary for it

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have done with new user.
just create another user and give it all privileges to it using:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```